# X11 proxy: Unsupported and WRONG

Tags: cookies, x11

I use tera term with xming on windows 10 to log-in ubuntu server.
When I run eog on the server, it didn't work and output following errors:

> PuTTY X11 proxy: Unsupported authorization protocol
>
> ** (eog:945): WARNING **: Could not open X display PuTTY X11 proxy: Unsupported authorisation protocol Cannot open display: Run 'eog
>   --help' to see a full list of available command line options.

I found some questions similar to this, but all seem for putty users. I don't use putty but tera term and all didn't work for me.
Why I got such errors? And how I can solve this?

Followings are about my envs.

> $ env | grep DISPLAY
>
> DISPLAY=localhost:10.0
>
> $ xauth list
>
> my-server/unix:11  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  XXXXXXXXXX
>
> my-server/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  XXXXXXXXXX

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting this error when trying from root account and it's working fine with your own user (e.g. if you are able to open Xclock), simply copy the .Xauthority file from user home to the root user home. it should work.

Thanks, 
K.